# I can't use the Android emulator in Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android-emulator, macos, android-sdk, android-studio

Can anyone help me run an Android emulator in Android Studio on Mac?

I tried to run it but it gives me the following messages:
`No USB devices or running emulators detected`
and
`minSdk(API 23, N preview) != deviceSdk(API 22)`

as portrayed in the given image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The app you are trying to run has a larger minimum SDK requirement than what is provided by the device you are trying to run on (22 vs. 23).

Check out the changes you need to make in your manifest file in [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) - specifically the part with:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```